# Double is not converting to an int

Tags: java, eclipse, int, double

This code I have written to convert `double` into `int` getting an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot cast from Double to int
```

This is my code

```
Double d = 10.9;    
int i = (int)(d);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Double` is a *wrapper* class on top of the primitive `double`. It can be cast to `double`, but it cannot be cast to `int` directly.

If you use `double` instead of `Double`, it will compile:

```
double d = 10.9;    
int i = (int)(d);
```

You can also add a cast to `double` in the middle, like this:

```
int i = (int)((double)d);
```

Answer (score 6):

thats because you cant mix unboxing (converting your `Double` to a double `primitive`) and casting.
try

```
int i = (int)(d.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Typo `convertig`. `n` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Double d = 10.9;
```

is your error. You are using wrapper classes instead of data types. Use

```
double d = 10.9;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast wrapper like Double to primitive type like int directly.

You can try this -

`int i = (int)((double)d);`

For more check following link -
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: `You can not cast wrapper like Double to primitive type like int directly.`Not always `(double) new Integer(5);` would work.