# Assignments and Generics compilation issue

Tags: java, generics

While learning `Generics` i found that first method that is `m1` compiles successfully where as second method `m2` fails to compile with following error message :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long

```
   class Test1 {

    <T extends Integer> void m1(T arg) {
        long i = arg;
    }

    void m2(int i) {
        Long l = i;// Compilation fails
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Comment: The type parameter T should not be bounded by a final type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double is not converting to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088522/double-is-not-converting-to-an-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is invalid

```
Long l = i;
```

because i is a primitive integer but l is an object of the type long, so that "conversion" will not happen automatically

you can get the value of that integer

```
Long l = Long.valueOf(i);
```

note that another options related to boxing-promoting primitives can be:

```
void m2(int i) {
    long x = i;
    Long l = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to utilize autoboxing feature for assigning a primitive value to an object type. But it doesn't work if the primitive type and the wrapper object type are not of the same type. For example, if you change `m2()` method like this, it should work:

```
void m2(long i) {
    Long l = i;
}
```

Or you can use the `valueOf()` method from `Long` wrapper class, as already said in an answer:

```
void m2(int i) {
        Long l = Long.valueOf(i);
}
```

But I would recommend to avoid auto-boxing as much as possible. It is bad practice. You can read the article here, why it is bad: https://effective-java.com/2010/05/the-advantages-and-traps-of-autoboxing/

The last point, you should remove the extension of `Integer` class for the type parameter `T`, as `Integer` is a final type and cannot be extended. Then your `m1()` method looks like that:

```
void m1(Integer arg) {
        long i = arg;
}
```